# Making a default HTML for specific file-types?

Tags: html, video, dynamic, default

Basicly, I want to make it so every time I open a ".mp4"-file from my media-server, it's displayed inside of a default "template".

I've submited an image trying to further explain my goal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTjqf.jpg

I apologize for not being to explain better than this, english isn't my first language.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: The problem with this question is it covers far too broad an area. What server-side languages do you have at your disposal? Is it designing the HTML code or getting the server to automatically produce it that's the problem? If both, you may want to ask separate question. Have you tried anything so far?